# MobileFirst 7.1 - Role-based access control

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

MobileFirst 8.0 feature [Role-based access control](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.analytics.doc/analytics/c_role_based_access_control.html). Can this similar configuration be made for MobileFirst 7.1? We are using version 7.1.0.0-MFPF-Server-IF201701200103.

Answer (score 0):

In MobileFirst Analytics 7.1, one can configure the role based access control via the server.xml slight with different terms. This can be located for both **analytics-service** and **analytics-ui** as follows seperately.

```
<application-bnd>
    <security-role name="worklightadmin">
        <user name="admin"/>
    </security-role>
        <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
        <user name="deployer"/>
    </security-role>
        <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
        <user name="monitor"/>
    </security-role>
        <security-role name="worklightoperator">
        <user name="operator"/>
    </security-role>
</application-bnd>
```

Comment: But that article for 8.0 states features like Viewing Access, who can view what. Does this configuration do the same?